# Convert cURL command line into Swift cURL does't work

Tags: ios, swift, curl

I use a OAuth2.0 API and it works very well with my cURL command line but not with swift code.

I read these other StackOverflow posts but it doesn't work: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356697/how-to-translate-curl-command-with-token-into-swift) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723703/how-to-convert-curl-command-to-swift).

Actually, my curl command is:
`curl -X POST --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET" https://api.myapp.fr/oauth/token`

and my swift code is:

```swift
        var dataStr: String!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.myapp.fr/oauth/token")! as URL)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("plain/text", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let params = ["grant_type" : "client_credentials",
                      "client_id" : "MY_CLIENT_ID",
                      "client_secret" : "MY_CLIENT_SECRET"] as Dictionary<String, String>
        let httpData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: params)
        request.httpBody = httpData

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error  in

            dataStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String!
            print("Data -> ")
            print(dataStr)
        })

        task.resume()
```

In the first case, the request is well formatted, and with swift it is not.
What did I wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you should use native Swift structs (URLRequest, URL, String) and don't use force unwrapping on optionals that might be nil (data for example in your completion handler). What error are you getting from your backend?

Comment: My backend only notice me that the request is not well formatted.

Comment: Then please include in your question the expected request body and the actual request body you are sending. Also, why are you setting Content-type to plain/text, when in your cURL request there is no Content-type header?

Comment: `let httpData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: params)`? Try `JSONSerialization` instead maybe?

Comment: Actually, this is not MY backend. but the Command Line cURL work and not my "swift translation". The only thing I have to do is to translate well my cURL line into swift langage.
The parameters must be POST parameters, for exemple in PHP: `$_POST["client_id"] = "MY_CLIENT_ID"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like your API expects the `key=value` style in the body. Try this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.myapp.fr/oauth/token")!
let params = [
    "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
    "client_id" : "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret" : "MY_CLIENT_SECRET"
]
let paramString = params.map {"\($0)=\($1)"}.joined(separator: "&") // for clarity and debugging

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: .utf8)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else {
        print("empty data")
        return
    }

    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(dataString)
}.resume()
```

This obviously does not handle special characters encoding. For example, if `MY_CLIENT_SECRET` contains an `=` or `&` sign, it will be interpreted very differently